# Why does this code print "2" instead of "3"?

Tags: c++

I want to write a function that gets a variable as input and increases its amount by one. I wrote the following code, but it doesn't work. How can I solve the problem?

````
using namespace std;
void func(int a)
{
    a+=1;
}
int main()
{
    int x=2;
    func(x);
    cout<<x;
}```
````

Comment: The duplicate answers your question exactly, but follow the duplicate link on that post to get a better understanding.

Comment: You pass by value meaning `a` is a copy of `x`. You modify the copy but that does not change the original.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the "Call by reference" method to change the value of the original variable. The following code shows the solution.

```
using namespace std;
void func(int* a)
{
    *a+=1;
}
int main()
{
    int x=2;
    func(&x);
    cout<<x;
}
```

Comment: "_You have to use the "Call by reference"_" Yet, your code doesn't show call by reference. If it did - the signature of the function would contain a reference: `void func(int& a)`

Comment: In `c++` its preferred to use `void func(int & a)` and leave the rest of the code the same as the original question code. You show in your code the `c` way since `c` does not have pass by reference.

Comment: Pointers can point to *anywhere*, which is why the *reference* is preferred over pointers.